# Visual Studio 2017 only has offline Nuget Packages for .NET Core 2.x. How to get online packages?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, nuget

I want to get NuGet Packages from Nuget online, but Visual Studio is only giving me 'Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages' as an option.

[image]

I have tried adding another package source using the following URLS:

- https://www.nuget.org
- https://packages/nuget.org

and a few others, but I keep getting the following error(s):

`[Package source] Unable to load the service index for source http://packagesource.
  An error occurred while sending the request.
  The remote name could not be resolved: 'packagesource'
[Nuget Online] The V2 feed at 'https://www.nuget.org/Search()?$filter=IsAbsoluteLatestVersion&searchTerm=''&targetFramework=''&includePrerelease=true&$skip=0&$top=26&semVerLevel=2.0.0' returned an unexpected status code '404 Not Found'.`

How can I get online packages for .NET Core?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I think the answer is:

1. Right click on the project and choose `Manage NuGet packages`.

[image]

2. Click on the settings cog in the top right corner of the Nuget packages tab.

[image]

3. In the settings dialog (as shown in the screenshot in the question), click on the `+` button.
4. Give the new source a name and a source of `https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json`.

[image]

This appears to work for me

Comment: This should be default behaviour anyway, you must have removed your package source manually somehow.

Comment: And you should removed that other one you have in the list, it's nonsense.

Comment: @DavidG right, it _should be_ the default behavior. Fresh install of VS2017 CE here, only offline package source is available.

Comment: Where did you find the `https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json` URL? I couldnt find it anywhere in the documentation on nuget.org OR microsoft.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I finally can make progress

Comment: Thanks! This worked, no idea why did they turn it off by default.

Comment: Fresh install of VS2019: same broken behaviour. Had to also manually add `https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json`

Answer (score -3):

You can try delete the resource "http://packagesource",or reduce the sort.

Comment: "Package source" and [http://packagesource](http://packagesource) are simply the default values that are prepopulated when you click to add a new source (the big green plus sign on the dialog)