# How to install FSharp.xUnit?

Tags: f#, xunit

I've installed Visual Studio 2017 and included the test package and the F# package. I'm trying to run a simple test using xUnit but it says xUnit is not found.

```
module HelloWorldTest

open FsUnit.xUnit
open Xunit

open System.Diagnostics

[<Fact>]
let ``Say Hello`` () =
    Assert.True(true)
```

Error

```
The namespace or module 'FsUnit' is not defined.
```

I tried installing the package with `dotnet` but that produces an error.

```
> dotnet add package FSharp.xUnit 
  Writing C:\Temp\tmp8DAB.tmp
info : Adding PackageReference for package 'FSharp.xUnit' into project  'C:\Users\mjohn\workspace\fsharp\hello-world\HelloWorld.fsproj'.
log  : Restoring packages for C:\Users\mjohn\workspace\fsharp\hello-world\HelloWorld.fsproj
...
error: Unable to find package FSharp.Core. No packages exist with this id in source(s): Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages
error: Unable to find package FsUnit.xUnit. No packages exist with this id in source(s): Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages
error: Unable to find package xunit. No packages exist with this id in source(s): Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages
error: Unable to find package xunit.runner.visualstudio. No packages exist with this id in source(s): Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages
error: Unable to find package FSharp.xUnit. No packages exist with this id in source(s): Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages
error: Unable to find package Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk with version (>= 16.0.0)
error:   - Found 1 version(s) in Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages [ Nearest version: 15.9.0]
error: Package 'FSharp.xUnit' is incompatible with 'all' frameworks in project 'C:\Users\mjohn\workspace\fsharp\hello-world\HelloWorld.fsproj'.
```

So how can I install xUnit for F#? This guide from MS unfortunately is lacking any of this information.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/unit-testing-fsharp-with-dotnet-test

**EDIT:**

After adding the NuGet package source

```
> dotnet add package FsUnit.xUnit
  Writing C:\Temp\tmp5BA6.tmp
info : Adding PackageReference for package 'FsUnit.xUnit' into project 'C:\Users\mjohn\workspace\fsharp\hello-world\HelloWorld.fsproj'.
log  : Restoring packages for C:\Users\mjohn\workspace\fsharp\hello-world\HelloWorld.fsproj
...
info :   CACHE https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/fsunit.xunit/index.json
info : Package 'FsUnit.xUnit' is compatible with all the specified frameworks in project 'C:\Users\mjohn\workspace\fsharp\hello-world\HelloWorld.fsproj'.
info : PackageReference for package 'FsUnit.xUnit' version '3.4.0' updated in file 'C:\Users\mjohn\workspace\fsharp\hello-world\HelloWorld.fsproj'.
```

Comment: Your debug output makes it seem like your project is not configured to look at nuget as a package source, try following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50484648/1346943)

Comment: This helped get the packages added via running `dotnet` but during building I'm still getting `The namespace or module 'FsUnit' is not defined.`.

Comment: I tried installing `FsUnit` via nuget in a F# application and was able to get it to compile with a `open FsUnit.Xunit` line at the top, are you sure the packages were all installed appropriately?

Comment: See my edit to the original post, I didn't see any error message. Is there any other way to verify? I'm new to all things .Net.

Comment: Try `dotnet list package`. I've tried this multiple times and it works fine for me (admittedly via LinqPAD, but it should be the same regardless of the IDE/editor).

Comment: When I run `dotnet list package` I get an error, `Required command was not provided.`.

Comment: What is your target framework? Here is a link to a working fsproj (can ignore Expecto for your case). https://github.com/dburriss/FsharpUnitTestFrameworks/blob/master/TestFrameworks/TestFrameworks.fsproj