# Could not add a new Scaffolded Item in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, visual-studio-2019

When I try to add a new *Scaffolded item* or a *Controller* in an **asp.net core** project it is giving me the following error. The IDE I am using is **Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.9.2**. There is already a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55090141/cannot-add-scaffolded-item-in-asp-net-core-web-application-vs-2017) answered but it did not resolve the issue.

[image: Error]

My project structure is as below.

[image: Project Structure]

The options for adding Controller and Scaffolded Item are visible.

[image]

Comment: have you a folder name "Pages" in your project?

Comment: Nope, but Controller yes

Comment: I have now created an empty asp.net project. In there no pages or controller folders. I will put a screenshot in the question

Comment: Install Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design on version 2.2.4

Comment: @PritomSarkar I tried but no luck

Comment: This answer will help you.please check it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56205382/there-are-no-scaffolders-supported-for-this-item-visual-studio-2019

Comment: Thanks a lot @PritomSarkar will try and get back